# Difference between lightning:button & ui:button

Tags: lightning, slds

I was going through the SLDS document and couldn't understand the difference between various UI components provided by SLDS vs Lightning components. For instance,

```
<ui:button> & <lightning:button>
```

They both do the same thing and rendered as a button on the component

Answer (score 8):

If you go thru the [Lightning base components release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_base_lightning_components.htm), you will notice that the Base components are more of an extended implementation of the existing UI components.

here's an extract of the related section

*You can find base Lightning components in the **lightning namespace to complement the existing ui namespace components**. In instances where there are matching ui and lightning namespace components, **we recommend that you use the lightning namespace component**. The lightning namespace components are optimized for common use cases. Beyond being equipped with the Lightning Design System styling, **they handle accessibility, real-time interaction, and enhanced error messages**.*

Over a period, the base components will have more features built into it which can be easily configured / controlled by additional attributes.